# .remove() not working in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading div element through jQuery .load() method like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".module-wrapper").load("index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&Itemid=974 .genericItemList");
});
```

Through that I get list of items, let's say 5 of them.

```
<div class="module-wrapper">
    <div class="genericItemList">
        <div class="genericItemView">Item 1</div>
        <div class="genericItemView">Item 2</div>
        <div class="genericItemView">Item 3</div>
        <div class="genericItemView">Item 4</div>
        <div class="genericItemView">Item 5</div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Now I want to use jQuery .remove() because I want to show just first 3 items.
HTML above is just example, in reality each item has a lot of HTML code so I want to use jQuery .remove() instead of CSS display:none.

I do that like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".module-wrapper .genericItemView:gt(2)").remove();
});
```

This is working only Chrome, but not in Firefox or IE, where I can see all 5 items.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can u create link pls

Comment: What is it View or List? The selector looks wrong in more than one way.

Comment: Correct your class name $(".module-wrapper .genericItemList:gt(2)").remove();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that code only runs after the elements have been loaded, you should put it in the callback function passed to [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".module-wrapper").load(
        "index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&Itemid=974 .genericItemList",
        function() {
            $(".module-wrapper .genericItemList:gt(2)").remove();
        }
    );
});
```

Your class selector may also be wrong, I tried to rectify it in the code above. It looks like you want to match descendants of `.module-wrapper` that expose the `genericItemList` class, but your original selector matches the elements that expose both the `module-wrapper` and `genericItemView` classes instead.

Comment: I got little confused about selectors, I updated my question with correct values.  
And your suggestion to put code in the callback function worked!  
Thanks.  

So this is the code:  `$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".module-wrapper").load(
        "index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&Itemid=974 .genericItemList",
        function() {
            $(".module-wrapper .genericItemView:gt(2)").remove();
        }
    );
});`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the success callback of the `load()` method to write dom manipulation

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".module-wrapper").load("index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&Itemid=974 .genericItemList", function(){
        $(".genericItemView:gt(2)", this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that was the solution as already Frédéric Hamidi proposed.

Answer (score 1):

change `genericItemList` to   `genericItemView`

```
 $(".module-wrapper .genericItemView:gt(2)").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your class name genericItemView to genericItemList.

```
$(".module-wrapper .genericItemList:gt(2)").remove();
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/mk7hm/)

Comment: I got a little confused with selectors, updated my question with correct code

Answer (score 1):

Change it `$(".module-wrapper.genericItemView:gt(2)").remove();` to `$(".module-wrapper .genericItemList:gt(2)").remove();`

Comment: I got a little confused with selectors, updated my question with correct code.

Answer (score 1):

add space  before .genericItemList

```
$(".module-wrapper .genericItemList:gt(2)").remove();
```

Comment: I got a little confused with selectors, updated my question with correct code.