# JQuery remove() appended div not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a chat room using socket.io and when a user connects to room i append the online users div with the code below

```
socket.on('updateusers', function(data) {

   var i = 0;
   $.each(data, function(key, value) {

      if(jQuery.inArray(key, users) == -1) {
         //key is users id
         users.push(key);
         if(scope.vm.user.name != key) {
            $('#users').append('<div id="user-'+key+'" onclick="send_individual_msg(\''+value+'\',\''+key+'\')">' + key + '</div>');
         } 
      }
   i++;
   });

});
```

When a user disconnects i'm trying to remove that appended div from online users

```
socket.on('removeusers', function(key) {

    $('#user-'+key).remove();
    users.splice( $.inArray(key,users) ,1 );

});
```

but it's only working on chrome and not on firefox.
Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: does the console give any errors?

Comment: no errors in console

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.remove() not working in IE and Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682375/remove-not-working-in-ie-and-firefox)

Comment: which values can the key variable have?

Comment: key is a random id the user gets from socket

Comment: @DimitrisKonomis you have to be sure that it doesn't contains any "illegal" value like ','

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik no it doesn't contains, is just numbers and letters

Comment: @DimitrisKonomis ok, so I suggest to log when the users are created and when you try to remove them, may be in the wrong order